# How are the two Galois groups are equal?

Tags: galois-theory

Let a polynomial $f(x)\in{K[x]}$ splits in $F$ as $f(x)=(x-a_{1})^{m_{1}}...(x-a_{n})^{m_{n}}$ where $a_{i}\in{F}$ are distinct. and $E:=K(b_{0},...,b_{n})$ where $b_{0},...,b_{n}$ are the coefficient of the polynomial $g(x)= (x-a_{1})...(x-a_{n})$. Then show that:

(a) $F$ is Galois over $E$, and

(b) $Aut_{E}F=Aut_{K}F$.

I fixed part (a). For part (b), I know $Aut_{E}F\subset{Aut_{K}F}$, but the other direction is killing me. I asked my professor and he told me it is immediate from (a) but I am still having trouble how is it immediate?

Comment: This looks fishy...isn't there some condition on the $\;a_i\;$ ? Say, like being all the roots of a set of polynomials over $\;K\;$ or stuff?

Comment: This is very wrong. You are not telling us something.

Comment: I edited the problem now.

Comment: Is $F$ the splitting field of $f$ over $K$?

Comment: Yes, $F$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $K$.

Comment: Ah, ok then! An algebraic extension is normal iff it is *the* splitting field of some non-empty set of polynomials over the base field.

Comment: You just need to show that an automorphism of $F$ fixing $K$ must also fix $E$. Use the fact that such an automorphism of $F$ must permute the distinct roots of $f$.

Comment: Yes, but how is it immediate from part (a)?

Comment: I'm not sure what the professor is getting at when he says that.

Comment: @Algebra, make some order in your question: what field is a subfield of which one? What are the fields extensions?

Comment: @ DonAntonio: The field $F$ is the extension field of the base field $K$.

Comment: @Algebra He means organize it like this: you have $K \subset E \subset F$ with $E = K(b_0, \cdots, b_n)$ and $F = K(a_1, \cdots, a_n)$.

Comment: Definitely would have made it easier for us to parse the question, and I daresay it would have made it easier for you to think about this problem if you had done this first as well. ;)